# The "New Contributor" dialog is masked

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, new-contributor-indicator

The *New Contributor* dialog is masked from where the comment section ends.
Here are some screenshots just to be more clear:

#### With no comments:

> [image]

#### With one comment:

> [image]

#### No masking with more comments:

> [image]

Comment: Fwiw, When I hit edit to add the "new-contributor-indicator" tag to the question, _that_ dialog was also cut off.

Comment: Maybe it is meant this way so we leave more "friendly" comments so we all get to see the whole dialog?

Comment: @rene Lol. What could that comment be then?

Comment: Back in the days I would be slinging insults at them but under the new Code of Conduct that has become tricky business ... ;)

Comment: @rene Or close the question - [that works too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrjSw.png) ;) The dialog shows up correctly above the "on hold" notice.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Looks like you misunderstood the bug. The dialog masks below the comment section - where the comments end

Comment: @BlackThunder Apologies if I was not clear - my comment was meant to imply "don't try reproducing the bug in closed questions; it seems to be *only* the space below the comment section that does it". It's most likely a z-index issue, so that wasn't a guarantee.

Comment: Correction: it's not z-index, it looks like the dialog can't extend outside the `<div class="post-layout">` that contains the question, on-hold notice and comments. That's about all I can tell with my mediocre "Inspect element" skills.

Comment: Related post on MSO (similar problem, same root cause): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389027/

Comment: trying hard to stop myself from editing the title to "The “New Contributor” dialog is masked _at last!_"

Comment: Possibly related: [Question's first two line and the upvote arrow are clamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332900/questions-first-two-line-and-the-upvote-arrow-are-clamped)

Comment: Test here now: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/68319/48726 As long as there is one comment

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow and Vi.SE as well. Pretty sure it's network-wide. The bug can be forcibly reproduced by deleting the div containing the comments from the developer tools in a browser.

Comment: @Olivia I tested it everywhere. This is why I posted here on M.SE

Comment: Two separate sites is technically enough to warrant a MSE post. There's about 100-200 sites IIRC, testing on all of them is hard

Comment: @Olivia You are right. *I tested it everywhere* - I meant to say **I tested it almost everywhere** They are basically all the same, except for some like Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Same problem, different UI element](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389069/6296561).

Comment: @Olivia Is that fixed now? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @BlackThunder looks like it - can't repro it either.

Comment: I'll confirm it if some other users can replicate it

Comment: @BlackThunder [meta-tag:status-norepro] for me

Comment: Maybe then, it is fixed. Flagging for moderator to put [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by Aaron: [Question's first two line and the upvote arrow are clamped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332900/questions-first-two-line-and-the-upvote-arrow-are-clamped/332911#332911)

The root cause here was a different change made to temporarily prevent scrolling at small screen sizes. The root cause of the scrolling was the new Share pop-up. With that identified (albeit not yet fixed), the temporary fix can be removed (and a small pile of related bugs completed).