# Question's first two line and the upvote arrow are clamped

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, advertising

It looks like  this, with upvote arrow and some content hidden

> [image]

while the markdown is this:

> [image]

I am using Safari 12.1.1. No ad-blocker and with Ghostery, got the same results. Refreshing it shows things for a split second.

[MacOS Mojave: Can not make changing background wallpaper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367969/macos-mojave-can-not-make-changing-background-wallpaper#comment492440_367969)

is the link to a comment on that question. If one removes the comment id, etc from it, everything works fine(except Spotify, but anyway).

Edited link:

[MacOS Mojave: Can not make changing background wallpaper](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367969/macos-mojave-can-not-make-changing-background-wallpaper)

Comment: reproduced the behaviour of the first link on my machine as well.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Was your browser Safari?

Comment: Actually, Chrome 76.0.3809.100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix is merged to `master`, but will take some time to get deployed over the weekend. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed on Chrome 76.0.3809.100.

However, the behaviour was observed to be even more critical in Firefox 68.0.2. The ad [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367969/macos-mojave-can-not-make-changing-background-wallpaper#comment492440_367969) totally "overpowered" the vote-up button:

[image]