# "New contributor" info text not visible

Tags: bug, design

Example 1: [link 1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/67269/package-manager-for-windows-using-multiple-versions-of-acrobat-reader-on-windo)

Example 2: [link 2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/67271/recommendations-for-a-python-game-bot)

If you move your mouse to *New contributor* then the text is not fully visible.

```html
<div class="js-new-contributor-popover s-popover fs-caption" style="top: 34px; left: -35.5px; width: 200px;">
            <div class="s-popover--arrow__tc"></div>
            <a href="/users/59125/awaaaaarghhh">Awaaaaarghhh</a> is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering.
Check out our <a href="/conduct">Code of Conduct</a>.        </div>
```

Tested on *Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)* and *Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 (64-Bit)*.

---

[image]

Comment: [The “New Contributor” dialog is masked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332845/the-new-contributor-dialog-is-masked)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog but it has no answer..

Comment: @ankiiiiiii On Meta Stack Exchange, closing a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question is allowed, especially in case of bug reports that have already been reported and not resolved yet.

Comment: bug was fixed !